# laravel blade check whether authenticated user exists in db

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm working on user request model. According to the below mentioned code , if the authenticated use id exists in database, he should see thumbs-up(font awesome), suppose if not he should see request button(font awesome). I'm using ajax and JQuery, Everything working fine but I'm not getting how to check it using if condition. someone help me Plz..

```
<div class="col-sm-1 follows" style="padding:0px">
    @if($followCount->user_id != Auth::user()->id) 
        <h2 id="deligate" value="1">
            <i class="fa fa-user-plus" data-toggle="tooltip" title="follow" ></i>
        </h2>
    @else(!empty($followCount->user_id)) 
        <h2 id="unfollow">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" data-toggle="tooltip" title="unfollow" style="display:none;color: #ff9933" id="test"></i>
        </h2>
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use only following code in blade file

```
@if(Auth::user())
    {{ code for authorise user. }}
</h2>
@else
   {{ Code for unauthorised user.}}
@endif
```

This check user authenticated user or not you have not need to add extra code for this.

Only use Auth::user() this check and match with your users table in DB.

Thank You and hope this work for you.

Comment: thanks for replying. I've tried this method. but else part won't work. I mean after refreshing page the authenticated user should see the thumbs up font-awesome.

Comment: sorry @Abhilash i didn't get you